# Get state list of a country

Tags: 8, symfony-services

In drupal 8 we can get country list using following code.

```
$countries = \Drupal::service('country_manager')->getList();
```

But how can I programatically get the list of state of each country?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Drupal core only keeps a record of countries, not all the states/administrative areas within each country.

However the [CommerceGuys addressing library](https://github.com/commerceguys/addressing) has that functionality. Example from their readme:

```
use CommerceGuys\Addressing\Subdivision\SubdivisionRepository;

$subdivisionRepository = new SubdivisionRepository();

// Get the subdivisions for Brazil.
$states = $subdivisionRepository->getAll(['BR']);
foreach ($states as $state) {
    $municipalities = $state->getChildren();
}
```

If need to get list of states as indexed array use the function 'getList()':

```
$states = $subdivisionRepository->getList(['BR']);
```

Then if you print the $states, you will get:

```
Array
(
    [AC] => Acre
    [AL] => Alagoas
    [AP] => AmapÃ¡
    [AM] => Amazonas
    [BA] => Bahia
    [CE] => CearÃ¡
    [DF] => Distrito Federal
    [ES] => EspÃ­rito Santo
    [GO] => GoiÃ¡s
    [MA] => MaranhÃ£o
    [MT] => Mato Grosso
    [MS] => Mato Grosso do Sul
    [MG] => Minas Gerais
    [PA] => ParÃ¡
    [PB] => ParaÃ­ba
    [PR] => ParanÃ¡
    [PE] => Pernambuco
    [PI] => PiauÃ­
    [RJ] => Rio de Janeiro
    [RN] => Rio Grande do Norte
    [RS] => Rio Grande do Sul
    [RO] => RondÃ´nia
    [RR] => Roraima
    [SC] => Santa Catarina
    [SP] => SÃ£o Paulo
    [SE] => Sergipe
    [TO] => Tocantins
)
```

Comment: Is there any code snippet available to check how to get state list using Address module?

Comment: @Clive, Thanks Clive. To add this code Address module should be enabled in the site. right?

Comment: @Clive, I didn't enable the Address module and added the code you mentioned above and while printing I am getting following: https://codeshare.io/a3DQ3k. I'm not able to access any private property of that object.

Comment: That's the example on their documentation page, if it doesn't work I'd raise a bug report

Comment: Its providing that data object. But I could't find how to get data from object.

Comment: @Clive, I dig into that library and found one function 'getList()' to get all states as an indexed array. Updated in your answer.

Comment: @Clive, when I put my code in to server, I'm getting following error:
Fatal error: Class 'CommerceGuys\Addressing\Subdivision\SubdivisionRepository'.

Comment: You probably need to install the addressing library. Add it to composer.json then run composer install on your prod server (or use your normal method if different)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60003/discussion-between-arun-and-clive).

Comment: @Clive, I ran `composer require commerceguys/addressing`. still same issue.

Comment: All I can really advise is to check what's different between your prod server and the environment  you had it working in

Answer (score 2):

The state list is not in drupal core. You need to get a feed from somewhere else.

Consider using the [address](https://www.drupal.org/project/address) module. This uses the commerce addressing library, providing you the state lists.